# Python Selenium Find Main Class of a Subclass

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find elements on a webpage :

The webpage contains lots of subclasses `"_4bl9" or "_4bl7"` and both of them have the same main class `"_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf"`

What i'm trying to do, is to find the main class `"_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf"` of this subclasses `"_4bl9"`

Here an example of the webpage:

```
<div class="_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf">
   <section>
      <div class="clearfix _ikh">
         <div class="_4bl9">

<div class="_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf">
   <section>
      <div class="clearfix _ikh">
         <div class="_4bl7">

<div class="_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf">
   <section>
      <div class="clearfix _ikh">
         <div class="_4bl9">
```

**This is my actual code :**

```
test = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_4bl9")
print(len(test))
```

**Output** :

```
2
```

Now I want to identify the exact `class="_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf"` of the two elements `"_4bl9"`

Comment: You can use xpath to find required element using: `//div[@class='_4bl9']/ancestor::div[@class='_3qn7 _61-3 _2fyh _3qnf']`